# How to display key value pair and add fields during onclick using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I need to display the object key and value in the fields. If user clicks on add button the new row of fields need to be added and able to insert values.

Initially,

```
var response =  {
  "json": {
    "response": {
      "data": [
        {
          "numbersUrlList": {
            "urlList": {
              "1": "http://www.press1.wav",
              "2": "http://www.press2.wav",
              "3": "http://www.press3.wav",
              "4": "http://www.press4.wav",
              "5": "http://www.press5.wav",
              "6": "http://www.press6.wav"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

When click on submit need to create a json as below.

```
var request = {
  "json": {
    "request": {
      "data": [
        {
          "numbersUrlList": {
            "urlList": {
              "1": "http://www.press1.wav",
              "2": "http://www.press2.wav",
              "3": "http://www.press3.wav",
              "4": "http://www.press4.wav",
              "5": "http://www.press5.wav",
              "6": "http://www.press6.wav",
              "7": "http://www.press7.wav",
              "8": "http://www.press8.wav"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I have also created a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/6Texj/292/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just change the `numberlist` in the response to get the desired json output onsubmit.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

myApp.controller('myController', function($scope) {

  $scope.countBlocks = 0;
  $scope.numberlist = [];

  $scope.onload = function() {

    $scope.response = {
      "json": {
        "response": {
          "data": [{
            "numbersUrlList": {
              "urlList": {
                "1": "http://www.press1.wav",
                "2": "http://www.press2.wav",
                "3": "http://www.press3.wav",
                "4": "http://www.press4.wav",
                "5": "http://www.press5.wav",
                "6": "http://www.press6.wav"
              }
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    };

    $scope.numberlist = $scope.response.json.response.data[0].numbersUrlList.urlList;


  };

  //adding new row for number list url

  $scope.addnumberlist = function() {
    var index = parseInt(Object.keys($scope.numberlist)[Object.keys($scope.numberlist).length - 1]);
    //console.log($scope.numberlist);
    //console.log(typeof($scope.numberlist));
debugger
    $scope.isCollapsed = true;
    $scope.displayremovebutton = true;
    $scope.numberlist[index + 1] = "http://www.press" + (index + 1) + ".wav";



  };

  $scope.removenumberlist = function(index) {
    //console.log($scope.numberlist);
    debugger
    delete $scope.numberlist[parseInt(index)];
  };

  $scope.submit = function() {
    // Request need to be created after adding url for 7 and 8
    $scope.response.json.response.data[0].numbersUrlList.urlList = $scope.numberlist;
    console.log($scope.response)
  }
  $scope.onload();
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 98%;
}
.option {
  width: 30%;
}
.option1 {
  width: 10%;
}
.option2 {
  width: 20%;
}
.option3 {
  width: 10%;
}
.form-control5 {
  width: 125%;
  height: 34px;
  margin-right: 80px;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #555;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.4.0.js"></script>

<link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController" class="row-fluid">
    <!-- START $scope.[model] updates -->
    <table class="table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td class="fieldname"><b>Numbers Url List</b>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div ng-show="!isCollapsed[$index]" ng-repeat="(key, value) in numberlist" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
              <div class="row col-sm-2" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <input type="text" name="count" class="form-control5" autocomplete="off" id="urlListNumber_{{$index}}" value="{{key}}" style="width: 100%; margin-right: 0px;">
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-10" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <input type="text" name="count" class="form-control5" autocomplete="off" id="numbersUrlList_{{$index}}" style="width: 120%;margin-right: 0px;" value={{value}}>
              </div><a href ng-click="removenumberlist(key)" ng-if="displayremovebutton">Remove</a>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td no-repeat>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addnumberlist()" style="float: right;">add</button>
          </td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submit()" style="float: right;">submit</button>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <!-- END TABLE -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes I want like this but it is auto-populating the value. I need to allow user to enter any value. When click on add button empty fields should display and after clicking on submit button only. It should create that json request with all the field values. And remove is not working. How can I remove the index as  **$scope.numberlist[index]**

Comment: Here, `$scope.numberlist.splice(index, 1);` would fail because `$scope.numberlist` is not an array but an object. Instead for `splice()` use `delete`

Comment: Now remove is working when declared as delete $scope.numberlist[index] inside removenumberlist();  . But the remove add function misbehaves after adding one row and trying to remove row (or) after removing the exhisting row and try to add row. Sorry, can you please help me. Because I am new to angularjs

Answer (score 0):

In the answer provided by @Stark Buttowski, removeItem function will not work correctly. Following id the proper implementation of the same:

In the view(send the key to be removed instead of the index of the key),

```
<input type="text" name="count" class="form-control5" autocomplete="off" id="numbersUrlList_{{$index}}" style="width: 120%;margin-right: 0px;" value={{value}}></div><a href ng-click="removenumberlist(key)" ng-if="displayremovebutton">Remove</a></div>
```

In the controller, use `delete` to remove the key received,

```
$scope.removenumberlist = function(key) {
        console.log(key);

        delete $scope.numberlist[key];
    };
```

Comment: Yes now remove works fine but when i add new row and remove. After that add is not working.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6Texj/299/   I have updated my fiddle. In this remove will work fine but after clicking remove button if i cick on add. add function is not working. Thanks in advance.